# How to show Owner of Defect in Rally

Tags: javascript, rally, owner, defects

I'm using /apps/1.29/sdk.js for the custom app. 
And I can get fields like "FormattedID" , "State", but I can not get the "Owner" printed out. Can you advise? thanks!

table.setCell(i, 5, '' + defect.Owner.LoginName + '
' + defect.Owner.DisplayName);  // these two ways both shows 'undefined' in the page. 
table.setCell(i, 6, '' + defect.State); //this is good.

Comment: Finally, I figured it out . :)

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, most objects in Rally have a _refObjectName property which represents the display name of the object.  Note that you'll want to make sure that Owner is not null first, since not all items may have an owner.